# htaccess url rewrite for specific page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a 'quick' login feature where I allow user to input parameter into URL so my website will detect and display the name, logo, background images and a password field to the user.

I am using this code `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]` for URL rewrite. So basically user just type `example.com/1`, in PHP will capture as `example.com/index.php?id=1` then proceed to load that respective id assets.

The problem is it didn't redirect me to the dashboard after login. It just stay at the same login page but I noticed the URL changed.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing you have a problem in your php then? Because if the url changed, the the weerite rorked... right?

Comment: Url chănge mean that the rewite work ok. But url chànge , page unchange, maybe err in route file?

Answer (score -1):

Redirect /index.html /new/

Redirect/index.html /default.html

Redirect /private/http://www.example.com/private/

Redirect /img/logo.gif http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif